# Can't compile typescript from npm scripts

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
{
  "name": "typescript-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc.cmd --outDir ./build --module commonjs ./src/*.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Project structure:

```
-project
    -src
        -main.ts
   -node_modules
        -.bin
            -tsc
            -tsc.cmd
            -tsserver
            -tsserver.cmd
        -typescript
            ...

    -package.json
    -tsconfig.json
```

Command: `npm run compile`

Error: `error TS6053: File 'src/*.ts' not found.`

---

I don't want to install typescript globally.

Comment: instead of `./src/*.ts` try `-p ./src`

Comment: Also you can just use `tsc` instead of `./node_modules/.bin/tsc.cmd` since you're already in node context and it will correctly load your tsc when run from npm script

Comment: Thanks! I also tried to do `-p ./src` but received an error: `error TS5057: Cannot find a tsconfig.json file at the specified directory: './src'.`

Comment: I see.. on your cmd, run this command. `./node_modules/.bin/tsc --init` it will generate the tsconfig.json file

Comment: To initialize your project use `tsc --init`. Then just modify options in `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json`. If you are done, compile everything just by running `tsc` without any parameters.

Comment: then move your options like `-p` `outDir` to `tsconfig.json`

Comment: I don't want to change the location of the `tsconfig.json` to `src` unless it is recommended by the community.

Comment: nope don't change the location... do you already have tsconfig.json?

Comment: https://github.com/Esemesek/express-typescript-starter -> Look in my project. `tsconfig.json` is in in root directory. All commands are run from root directory of your project. And `build` script is just `tsc` because all the configuration is done in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: I cosign with @KacperWiszczuk

Comment: @AdityaParab it's working: `tsc --outDir ./build --module commonjs -p ./src -p tsconfig.json` please post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!!